# JPA Managed entities merge operations without cascade options

Tags: hibernate, transactions, jpa-2.0

i am trying to update an Entity inside a transaction, first i select the entity using its primary key, then lazily loaded its child entities and made changes to its properties through setter methods. After that when i merge the parent object, automatically all its child objects with OneToMany relations gets updated. Although this is the required functionality, but i am little confused with this behavior because i didn't specified any cascade options for the child entities. In order to make sure, i even tried a non-relational table, just queried using find JPAQL and changed its properties. When the transaction commited after the merge operation of the main entity, this non-relational entity also gets updated along with others. I am not sure this is the correct behavior, or its the problem of understanding the JPA and merge operation inside transactions.

My Parent class

```
class Student
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Integer id;

private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
private List<Subjects> subjects;

public Integer getId(){
return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id){
this.id=id;
}
public String getName(){
return name;
}
public void setName(String name){
this.name=name;
}
```

My Child class

```
Class Subjects

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@JoinColumn(name = "student", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Student student;

public Integer getId(){
return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id){
this.id=id;
}

public String getCourse(){
return course;
}
public void setCourse(String course){
this.course=course;
}
```

Non-Relational Entity is just an Entity class without any relations with this selected entity classes. I added it to just to check whether the updations happened due to any relations specified in the entity classes(Even without cascade options).

My Transactional Update function.

```
    Object obj1 = this.transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {

Category category=findById('2'); //Non-Related entity with Student or Subject
category.setName('new category');

Student student=findStudentById(1);
for(Subjects subjects:student.getSubjects()){
subjects.setCourse("test");
}
student.setName("student1");
entityManager.merge(student);

   return true;
   }
 });
```

so the final outcome after merging and transaction commit is that, all the tables(Student, Subjects and Category)updated.

Comment: Post the code instead of describing it. And define what a non-relational table is.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks for your response, i had added the relevant codes also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so you're surprised that changes made to entities are persisted without even calling `merge()` or any other method.

That's one of the main points of JPA/Hibernate and attached entities: you modify them, and since they're attached to a persistence context, all these changes are transparently persisted when needed (at most, at the end of the transaction).

`merge()` is used to copy the state of a detached entity to an attached one.

Read [this part of the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate) for more details.

Comment: thanks you have cleared my doubts. So even if i didnt call the merge for the parent entity classes all the changes made to the entity classes will be persisted to the database when the transaction gets commited.

Comment: Yes, you got it. As soon as the entity manager is closed (which usually happens when the transaction ends), the entities becoe detached, and the changes made on these entities are not transparently persisted anymore.

Comment: @JBNizet may I please ask for your help with this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550585/properly-modify-object-with-manytoone-relationship-in-spring-mvc-hibernate-ap). I've been reading your many answers on similar question, but couldn't find solution on my own.