# Properly modify object with @ManyToOne relationship in Spring MVC + Hibernate app

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, updating, many-to-one

After days of torture to resolve this issue and reading everything I could find on SO I decided to ask. I'm having trouble understanding what I read here on [Hibernate site](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-modifying), so I'll explain my situation.

I have object `student` that contains object `program`:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "PROGRAM_FK", nullable = false)
private Program program;
```

In my service method I want o change/update only program for a student:

```
 public void edit(Student student) {
     Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

     // Retrieve existing student via id
     Student existingStudent = (Student) session.get(Student.class, student.getStudentId());

     // Assign updated program to this student
     existingStudent.setProgram(student.getProgram()); <-- This is not working as I would want it! -->

     session.merge(existingStudent);
 }
```

I want to change the **program for the student**, but not the program itself. How can I achieve this? And can someone please tell me, in this particular situation, who is parent and who is child? Should I use CascadeType.MERGE at all? Should I use merge() method or something else? I can't deduce this from reading documentation, if someone would be so kind to explain it on this particular case, so I can finally understand it... Thank you.

Program object:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="program")
private Set<Student> students;
```

I'm calling my edit method from controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST, params="edit")
    public String postEditStudent(
            @Validated({Student.StudentEditChecks.class}) @ModelAttribute("studentAttribute") Student student,
            BindingResult result,
            Model model) {

        logger.debug("Received request to edit student");

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("programList", programService.getAll());
            return "editStudent";
        }
        else {
            studentService.edit(student);
            return "redirect:/essays/main/student/list";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide details of where are you calling the edit method and how. When calling the edit method does the student parameter have Program set on it. How did you infer that its not working. Did you get any exception?

Comment: Student is the owning side, so setting the reference on it seems right. Can you post the Program code and how it referenecs the Student?

Comment: @Pratik I'm just calling it in the controller like this: `studentService.edit(student);` nothing else. I had different errors with my particular implementation, but what I presented here is the core of the problem, otherwise, question would be huge. How to update object with this particular relationship, that's what  I would like to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you use inputs that contain too much information for what you want to do. And that makes everything confusing.

All you want to do is setting an existing program on an existing student. The only inputs you need for this task are the student ID and the program ID. And if you had only those inputs, the solution would become obvious:

```
@Transactional
public void setProgramOnStudent(Long studentId, Long programId) {
    Student student = (Student) session.get(Student.class, studentId);
    Program program = (Program) session.load(Program.class, programId);
    student.setProgram(program);
}
```

Note that I used `load()` and not `get()` to load the program, because you don't ven need th state of the program, only a reference to the existing program. It would also work with `get()`, but it would execute an additional, useless seelct query to load the state of the program.

Comment: This is great advise, thank you. After I set an existing program on an existing student, what session method should I use for saving the change to db? And how should I set CascadeType for that method? @JBNizet

Comment: The above code is sufficient. You don't need to call any save, persist, merge or whatever. Attached entities are transparently persistent, and the change applied to the Student state will thus be flushed and commited to the database automatically at the end of the transaction. The above also doesn't rely on any cascade. All it does is change te value of one field of one entity: Student. Cascades are irrelevant.